# In Django, how do I create an initial dataset for users when they register

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

It's a pretty simple concept.

Jane signs up for xyz service.

When she does so, her account is pre-filled with 20 widgets.

Then she can add her own widgets later.

I've been doing this with a intermediary table that grabs items from a a widget model and then applies the user. But it's convoluted and ugly. But maybe that is just the way it has to be.

How would you do this? Have you seen tutorials for it? Any advice would be very helpful.

Would it be fixtures import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something has to denote the default items, whether this is an intermidiary table, or an `is_default` flag or a hardcoded list all have their pros and cons

Storing them in teh db with a flag or in their own table is nice because it allows you to change the defaults on the fly.

Hardcoding them in your code would require reloading/redeploying of your app to change, but would make it so only the developers could change them.

I'm sure there are a couple more ways too!

Comment: It's good to know I'm not missing anything. I'll be sorting then in there own table and doing a post_save() to add the records. Thanks for the thinking.